# Merging two or more "lists" in columns?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, split, array-formulas, textjoin

Trying to find a way to merge multiple lists while preserving the order the items are in, right-to-left, **then** top-to-bottom.

Example:

```
A B C
D E
F
G H
```

should become:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
```

and not

```
A
D
F
G
B
E
H
C
```

I have found countless sites with people explaining how I can just stick one list to the end of the previous (as shown in the "and not" example), but that is precisely **not** what I'm searching for.

Potential duplicate entries don't matter.

[Editable example sheet here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Pyy6jzK8eOBWcEDjX7Df60LH1BYswzbJKMvVF5WlAg/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sample formula

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A3:C28),","))
```

- In this case, your shared Spreadsheet is used as the sample values.
- From your "Desired Output" in your shared Spreadsheet, I thought that you are using the range of "A3:C28". If you want to use the range of "A3:C29", please modify above formula.
- Flow is as follows.

  1. All values are converted to a string using `TEXTJOIN`.

     - In this case, `,` is used as the delimiter. If `,` is included in the values, please change this.
  2. The string value is splitted for putting to each cell using `SPLIT`.
  3. The value is transposed using `TRANSPOSE`.

#### Result:

In this sample, the formula is put to the cell "F3".

[image]

#### Note:

- If you want to remove the duplicated values, please use `UNIQUE` like `=UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A3:C28),",")))`.

#### References:

- [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136)
- [TRANSPOSE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262)

Comment: This is exactly it, perfect, thank you! Kinda been going a little crazy over this, having to do it by hand every time.

Comment: @DeBedenHasen Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

while previous answer may work for small dataset:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♦", 1, G3:I), "♦"))
```

[image: 0]

---

if you got huge dataset and textjoin shall output limit error, you can use this limitless approach:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(G3:G="",,"♦"&G3:I&"♦")),,99^99)),,99^99), "♦")),
 "where not Col1 starts with ' '", 0),,1)
```

[image]